# Group Array of Objects based on group

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects as below and it has to be grouped based on the property Group
Input Object:

```
 [
    {
     
      "MsgID": "280",
      "Date": "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      "DisplayDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
      "Group": "2"
      }
    },
    {
      "MsgID": "300",
      "Date": "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      "DisplayDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
      "Group": "1"
    },   {
      "MsgID": "320",
      "Date": "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      "DisplayDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
      "Group": "1"
    }
  ]
```

Output of the object should be grouped as below

```
[
  {
    "Group": "1",
    "groupItems": [
      {
        "MsgID": "300",
        "Date": "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
        "DisplayDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
        "Group": "1"
      },   {
      "MsgID": "320",
      "Date": "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
      "DisplayDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
      "Group": "1"
    }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Group": "2",
    "groupItems": [
      {
        "MsgID": "280",
        "Date": "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
        "DisplayDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
        "Group": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How to do it in optimal way by using es6 syntaxes. If there are multiple items having same group then groupItems property should have all those in array.

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: Starting with the `map()` or `reduce()` array methods are good starting points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.reduce` to group the items by `Group` and then `Object.values` to get the resulting objects:

```js
const arr = [
  { 
    "MsgID": "280",
    "Date": "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "DisplayDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Group": "2"
  },
  {
    "MsgID": "300",
    "Date": "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "DisplayDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Group": "1"
  },
  {
    "MsgID": "320",
    "Date": "2020-12-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "DisplayDate": "2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Group": "1"
  }
];

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,item) => {
  const { Group } = item;
  const prev = acc[Group] ;
  acc[Group] = prev
    ? { ...prev, groupItems: [...prev.groupItems, item] }
    : { Group, groupItems: [item] };
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```